# Why is one text element of a table not aligning with the rest?

Tags: html, css, django

I'm making a game based off of a gameshow with Django, and want the users to be able to select a specific episode to play. The page in question is after the users have selected a year from the database, when they select the month from which they want to play. For some reason, no matter which year is selected, the month of March is always not aligned with the rest of the text. This occurs if March is the first, second, or third available month. I have not styled it differently from the others, and when I click inspect it randomly aligns with the rest (pictures attached). I've attached the code from episode_month.html and main.css. If anyone could help me align this month or give insight as to why it's above the others I'd appreciate it--it's been driving me crazy!

episode_months.html:

```
{% extends "game/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <div class = "mode">Available Months</div>
    <div class = "mode_info">{{ year }}</div>
    <table class = "board">
        {% for month_group in months %}
            <tr class = "row">
            {% for month in month_group %}
                {% if month != "" %}
                    <th class = "tile-months board_cat">
                        <a class = board_month href="/episode_mode/{{year}}/{{month.0}}/"> &nbsp; {{ month.1 }} &nbsp; </a>
                    </th>
                {% else %}
                    <th class = "tile-months board_month"></th>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endblock content %}
```

main.css (relevant):

```
.board {
    flex: 1;
    position: static;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
    display: grid;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
  }
    
  .row {
    flex: 1;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
.tile-months {
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    padding: 2%;
    margin: auto;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Swiss 911';
    background: #060ce9;
    border: 3px solid #000;
  }

  .board_month {
    font-size: 2.5vw;
    color: #FFCC00;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

[image: months table]
[image: inspect page]

Comment: `<a class = board_month` should be `<a class='board_month'`

Comment: I fixed it, but March is still not aligned.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser data? Command+Shift+Delete on chrome.